# Создать PictureBox в своём классе

Tags: c#, графика, форма, примитивы

Как в контексте своего класса создать картинку?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form{
    myGraphics graphics = new myGraphics();
    public Form1(){
        InitializeComponent();
        graphics.Draw();
    }

}
internal class myGraphics{
    public void Draw()
    {
        var bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);

        bmp.SetPixel(0, 0, Color.BlueViolet);
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
    }
}
```

Имя «pictureBox1» не существует в текущем контексте

Comment: Ну задайте вместо свойств `pictureBox1` просто свои размеры какие-то `new Bitmap(200, 200)`, например. Я только не понял - у вас на форме есть картинка с именем `pictureBox1` или откуда это взялось?

Comment: да на форме картинка pictureBox1

Comment: А, ну наверное это же внутренняя переменная класса Form1, её видно в методах класса Form1 соответственно.

Comment: CS0236: Инициализатор поля не может ссылаться на нестатическое поле, метод или свойство «имя»

Answer (score 1):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form{
    myGraphics graphics = new myGraphics(pictureBox1);
    public Form1(){
        InitializeComponent();
        graphics.Draw();
    }

}
internal class myGraphics{
    PictureBox pictureBox;

    public myGraphics(PictureBox p)
    {
         pictureBox = p;
    }

    public void Draw()
    {
        var bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox.Width, pictureBox.Height);

        bmp.SetPixel(0, 0, Color.BlueViolet);
        pictureBox.Image = bmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, оставляйте более развернутые ответы.